# windows - scan filenames and move files to dirs and subdirs with names derived from filenames

Tags: batch-file, cmd, copy, filenames, move

I (unfortunately) have thousands of files which need to be reorganized into different folder scheme.
All my files follow the pattern:

```
d:\mainfolder\0001.pic\AMY_CAT_file1.jpg
d:\mainfolder\0001.pic\EVE_CAT_file1.jpg
d:\mainfolder\0002.pic\AMY_BIRD_file2.jpg
d:\mainfolder\0002.pic\EVE_BIRD_file2.jpg
```

what I'm looking for is a *.bat file that could move the files into folders that go like this:

```
...\CAT_\AMY\0001.pic\AMY_CAT_file1.jpg
...\CAT_\EVE\0001.pic\EVE_CAT_file1.jpg
...\BIRD\AMY\0002.pic\AMY_BIRD_file2.jpg
...\BIRD\EVE\0002.pic\EVE_BIRD_file2.jpg
```

in other words, the files would have to be moved:

1. into the subsubfolder named after source directory of a file
2. which is inside the folder named after 1st to 3rd
   symbol, and finally
3. which is inside the folder which is named after the 5th to 8th symbol in the filename

I realise it might sound confusing, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is your best try so far? where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`1st to 3rd symbol` and `5th to 8th symbol` is a bad idea, as the names might be of different lengths (see `cat`, `bird`, and possibly `elephant`; or `Eve`, `Amy`, and possibly `Stephan`), but you have there a nice underscore that can serve as delimiter:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd /d "d:\mainfolder"
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /s /b *.jpg') do (
  for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=_" %%A in ("%%~nF") do (
    set folder=%%~dpF
    for %%X in (!folder:~0^,-1!) do (
      ECHO move "%%F" "...\%%B\%%A\%%~nxX\%%~nxF"
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: your hint has worked, but only if there is already a destination folder, that is ...\%%B\%%A\%%~nxX in place. Is there a chance to create those folder trees on the go?

Comment: nvm, figured it out :) Thanks everybody